# Python class can't be updated after being compiled

Tags: python, module, pyc

I just started with python a couple of days ago, coming from a C++ background. When I write a class, call it by a script, and afterwards update the interface of the class, I get some behaviour I find very unintuitive.

Once successfully compiled, the class seems to be not changeable anymore. Here an example:

testModule.py:

```
class testClass:
    def __init__(self,_A):
        self.First=_A

    def Method(self, X, Y):
        print X
```

testScript.py:

```
import testModule

tm=testModuleB.testClass(10)
tm.Method(3, 4)
```

Execution gives me

```
3
```

Now I change the argument list of `Method`:

```
def Method(self, X):
```

, I delete the testModule.pyc and in my script I call

```
tm.Method(3)
```

As result, I get

```
TypeError: Method() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does the script not use the updated version of the class? I use the Canopy editor but I saw this behaviour also with the python.exe interpreter.

And apologies, if something similar was asked before. I did not find a question related to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python loads the code objects into memory; the `class` statement is executed when a file is first imported an a class *object* is created and stored in the module namespace. Subsequent imports re-use the already created objects.

The `.pyc` file is only used the *next* time the module is imported *for the first time that Python session*. Replacing the file will not result in a module reload.

You can use the [`reload()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) to force Python to replace an already-loaded module with fresh code from disk. Note that any and all other direct references to a class are not replaced; an instance of the `testClass` class (`tm` in your case) would still reference the old class object.

When developing code, it is often just easier to restart the Python interpreter and start afresh. That way you don't have to worry about hunting down all direct references and replacing those, for example.

Answer (score 2):

`testModule` is already loaded in your interpreter. Deleting the `pyc` file won't change anything. You will need to do `reload(testModule)`, or even better restart the interpreter.

Answer (score -1):

Deleting the `.pyc` file cannot do the change in your case. When you import a module for the first time on the interpreter, it gets completely loaded on the interpreter and deleting the files or modifying won't change anything.

Better restart the interpreter or use the built-in `reload` function.